# FHIR Appointment and AppointmentResponse in a Resquest->Response sync model

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am implementing a patient portal where patients can book an appointment based on Hospital schedules slots availability. Process is implemented in a Request->Response synchronous model, so once Appointment Resource is sent using POST to create the appointment, synchronous response knows if appointment is accepted and booked.
Which must be the body response in this situation:
1- No body and just HTTP Status 200
2- HTTP Status 200 and Body with the created Appointment
3- HTTP Status 200 and Body with an AppointmentResponse

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Option #2: HTTP Status 200 and Body with the created Appointment

Appointment response comes from the invitees later

Comment: Probably, same 200 response should be returned even when appointment request is declined or not completed. As the property participantStatus in AppointmentResponse will have that indication.

Comment: POSTing the Appointment just creates the appointment.  The 200 says that the appointment was successfully created.  It doesn't give any indication whether any of the invitees agree to participate.  It's equivalent to creating an entry in your electronic calendar.  If the calendar website is down, you'll get a failure.  If it's up, you'll get a success.  Invited recipients will then send separate POSTs (AppointmentResponses) to accept or decline the invite.  (And some might not respond at all...)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your responses and explanations. Now for me is clear which is the correct option (#2) and why ;-)